# ¿Cómo comprobar con Angular si un archivo existe en Firebase Storage?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, observable

estoy trabajando en un proyecto de angular donde almaceno datos de servicios en **Firebase Firestore** y las imágenes en **Firebase Storage**, mi duda surge cuando llamo a dichos datos en **Firestore**, me los retorna normal pero con un campo de esos datos necesito hacer la comprobación si existe una imagen con dicho valor retornado. Espero me entiendan y puedan ayudarme.
Les dejo mi código:

```js
fetchAllServices() {
  return this.firestore.collection < Service > ('services', ref => ref.orderBy('order', 'asc')).valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).pipe(
    map(changes => {
      return changes.map((c: Service) => {
        let service: any;
        const tools = (Array.isArray(c.tools)) ? (
          c.tools.map(tool => {
            const toolImageUrl = this.getImageTool(tool.image);
            return { ...tool,
              urlImage: toolImageUrl
            };
          })) : null;
        const serviceImageUrl = (c.image !== undefined) ? this.getImageService(c.image) : null;
        const serviceImageThumbUrl = (c.image_thumb !== undefined) ? this.getImageThumb(c.image_thumb) : null;
        service = { ...c,
          urlImage: serviceImageUrl,
          urlImageThumb: serviceImageThumbUrl,
          tools
        };
        return service;
      });
    })
  );
}

getImageService(serviceImageName: string) {
  return this.storage.ref(`services/images/${serviceImageName}.jpg`).getDownloadURL();
}

getImageThumb(serviceImageThumbName: string) {
  return this.storage.ref(`services/images/${serviceImageThumbName}.png`).getDownloadURL();
}

getImageTool(toolImageName: string) {
  return this.storage.ref(`tools/images/${toolImageName}.png`);
}
```

El detalle está cuando el archivo no existe en Firebase: en la consola del navegador me retorna lo siguiente

```js
Unhandled Promise rejection: FirebaseStorageError  {
  code_: "storage/object-not-found",
  message_: "Firebase Storage: Object 'services/images/undefined.png' does not exist.",
  serverResponse_: "{↵  "
  error ": {↵    "
  code ": 404,↵    "
  message ": "
  No… not get object ",↵    "
  status ": "
  GET_OBJECT "↵  }↵}",
  name_: "FirebaseError"
};
Zone: < root > ;
Task: Promise.then;
Value: FirebaseStorageError  {
  code_: "storage/object-not-found",
  message_: "Firebase Storage: Object 'services/images/undefined.png' does not exist.",
  serverResponse_: "{↵  "
  error ": {↵    "
  code ": 404,↵    "
  message ": "
  No… not get object ",↵    "
  status ": "
  GET_OBJECT "↵  }↵}",
  name_: "FirebaseError"
}
undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

:D
Hasta donde sé, el método `.getDownloadURL()` retorna una [promesa](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference.html#get-downloadurl), entonces podrías intentar lo siguiente:

```
getImageService(serviceImageName: string) {
  return this.storage.ref(`services/images/${serviceImageName}.jpg`).getDownloadURL()
    .then(url => url) // Si todo bien, retorna la URL
    .catch(error => {
      // Error, puede que no exista la imagen
      console.log('Error:', error)
      return null;
    })
}
```

Referencia: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url

---

Aparte, creo que podrías reducir los métodos `getImageService()`, `getImageThumb()` y `getImageTool()` a una sola función `getImage()`:

```
getImage(ImageName: string, Path: string, Extension: string) {
  return this.storage.ref(`${Path}/${ImageName}.${Extension}`).getDownloadURL()
    .then(url => url) // Si todo bien, retorna la URL
    .catch(error => {
      // Error, puede que no exista la imagen
      console.log('Error:', error)
      return null;
    })
}
```

E implementarla así:

```
fetchAllServices() {
  return this.firestore.collection < Service > ('services', ref => ref.orderBy('order', 'asc')).valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).pipe(
    map(changes => {
      return changes.map((c: Service) => {
        let service: any;
        const tools = (Array.isArray(c.tools)) ? (
          c.tools.map(tool => {
            const toolImageUrl = this.getImage(tool.image, 'tools/images', 'png');
            return { ...tool,
              urlImage: toolImageUrl
            };
          })) : null;
        const serviceImageUrl = this.getImage(c.image, 'services/images', 'jpg');
        const serviceImageThumbUrl = this.getImage(c.image_thumb, 'services/images', 'png');
        service = { ...c,
          urlImage: serviceImageUrl,
          urlImageThumb: serviceImageThumbUrl,
          tools
        };
        return service;
      });
    })
  );
}
```

Intenta a ver y me avisas que tal :D